# How can I make the proxy type just for implementing some trait for it?

Tags: rust

I want to implement some foreign traits (`ToSql` and `FromSql` from `diesel` crate) for the foreign types (`chrono::Duration` from `chrono` crate). I did this:

```
pub struct ChronoDurationProxy(pub chrono::Duration);
```

Then I implemented needed traits for this `ChronoDurationProxy` type. However,
I'd like the user not to care much about the proxy type. So, the only thing I knew from what I could do in such situation was implementing traits for `deref`. But I am stuck because, I don't quite understand the difference between `Deref` and `AsRef`. So, I implemented both of them, but don't really know, should I do that or not:

```
impl AsRef<chrono::Duration> for ChronoDurationProxy {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &chrono::Duration {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl std::ops::Deref for ChronoDurationProxy {
    type Target = chrono::Duration;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}
```

Neither I know any other ways of providing the most transparent way of such types proxying, hence the question.

Comment: Diesel already supports [`chrono` as a feature](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/blob/4b7fbbfed377dfba4f8e259b6c600b62b5dad256/diesel/Cargo.toml#L17). So you don't actually need to do that for this particular type. Of course, the question you are asking might still be worth answering. I *think* I have seen a similar question here before... but not quite sure.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt diesel does not support `chrono::Duration` and never will.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**: they are opposite things. `Deref<T>` explains how to derefence a type (`*T`), `AsRef<T>` explains what is a `&T`. In your case, you want to use `Borrow` trait (and not `AsRef`), as explained in the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48887413/why-does-t-not-implement-asreft/48887786).

---

`Deref` tells to the compiler what is the result when you dereference your type (your type is like a smart pointer in this case):

```
struct UIntRef<'a>(&'a u32);

impl<'a> std::ops::Deref for UIntRef<'a> {
    type Target = u32;

    fn deref(&self) -> &u32 {
        &self.0
    }
}

fn get_u32(_: u32) {}

fn main() {
    let u = UIntRef(&42);

    get_u32(*u); // I get an u32 when I deref an UIntRef
}
```

`AsRef` is a useful abstraction when a thing has a meaning as a "view" on the memory. For example, a `Vec` or an array are collections of things contiguous in memory. When you only need to **read** those things, you use a slice (`AsRef<[T]>` is a slice) that is a **view** on the memory. So, an array and a `Vec` can both be seen as views on the memory when you take their reference. Thus you can write:

```
fn get_view_on_things<T>(_: T)
where T: AsRef<[i32]> {}

fn main() {
    get_view_on_things(&vec![1, 2, 3]);
    get_view_on_things(&[1, 2, 3]);
}
```

---

To answer your underlying question, you cannot make things totally transparent for the user, and that is a good thing. Newtypes are made to add meaning, not to be transparent:

```
struct Miles(f32);
struct Kms(f32);

fn take_a_distance(_: Miles) {}

fn main() {
    take_a_distance(1.23);
    // Cannot compile: What does the use wants ?

    take_a_distance(Miles(1.23));
    // Oh, now that's clear
}
```

**However**, because in the both case you can get a reference on the same type, you can implement `Borrow` for your newtype, as in this example:

```
extern crate chrono;

use std::borrow::Borrow;

struct ChronoDurationProxy(chrono::Duration);

impl Borrow<chrono::Duration> for ChronoDurationProxy {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &chrono::Duration {
        &self.0
    }
}

fn take_a_duration<T>(dur: T) where T: Borrow<chrono::Duration> {
    let dur = dur.borrow(); // here we get a `&chrono::Duration`
    println!("{:?}", dur)
}

fn main() {
    let dur_1 = chrono::Duration::days(1);
    let dur_2 = ChronoDurationProxy(dur_1);

    take_a_duration(dur_1);
    take_a_duration(dur_2);
}
```

Comment: So, do you think that it was good that I implemented both of these traits?

Comment: @VictorPolevoy I do not think so. There are both useless in your case. But your question will make me ask another one.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48887413/why-does-not-t-implement-asreft

Comment: Why useless? The user may pass my proxy type as `chrono::Duration` reference to a function - this already eases pain of introduction a proxy type.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy My answer is now complete. I will remove my comments because they are not useful anymore.

Comment: Then another problem: I don't quite understand the difference between `AsRef` and `Borrow`...

Comment: @VictorPolevoy I have already linked a question about this in the TL;DR