# Why does T not implement AsRef<T>?

Tags: rust

This code does not compile:

```
fn ref_on_int<T>(_: T) where T: AsRef<i32> {}

fn main() {
    ref_on_int(&0_i32)
}
```

because

```
the trait bound `i32: std::convert::AsRef<i32>` is not satisfied
```

Why is it so?

This could be useful for example with a newtype like

```
struct MyInt(i32);

impl AsRef<i32> for MyInt {
    /* etc. */
}
```

then you could indifferently pass a reference on an `i32` or a reference on a `MyInt`, because in the memory we have in both cases an `i32`.

Comment: I think that is what `Borrow` is for. I'm not totally sure of the difference between `AsRef` and `Borrow` but the latter is implemented for `&T`.

Comment: @rodrigo Oh, ok. Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: @rodrigo `AsRef` seems to be the more appropriate one here, as the second example includes conversion.

Comment: @ljedrz Sorry it was not the goal, I will change my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`AsRef` and `Borrow` are pretty similar at first glance, but they are used for different things. [The Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/first-edition/borrow-and-asref.html#which-should-i-use) describes the difference between them pretty well:

> Choose `Borrow` when you want to abstract over different kinds of
>   borrowing, or when you’re building a data structure that treats owned
>   and borrowed values in equivalent ways, such as hashing and
>   comparison.
>
> Choose `AsRef` when you want to convert something to a reference
>   directly, and you’re writing generic code.

In your case `Borrow` is a more reasonable choice because there is no conversion involved.

As for the question of why `AsRef` is not implemented between different integral types, I guess this would go against the intent of Rust to be expressive about casts; I think it's similar to the question [Why can't I compare two integers of different types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48225587/why-cant-i-compare-two-integers-of-different-types).

Comment: But the question is rather not _why is not `AsRef` implemented between different integral types?_ but _why is not `AsRef<T>` implemented for `&T`_?

Comment: @rodrigo true - I'm just referring to the original state of the question, which is IMO an interesting twist on this issue.

Comment: @ljedrz: How could you implement `AsRef` between integral? To return a `&i64` you need a `i64` stored somewhere, and you cannot summon it out of the ether when all you have is a `i32` :x

Comment: @MatthieuM. I was thinking of cases where the size is the same, e.g. obtaining a `&i32` from an `u32`; you're right about different sizes, of course.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an [authoritative answer by Aaron Turon](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24140):

> `Borrow` provides a blanket implementation `T: Borrow<T>`, which is *essential* for making the above collections work well. `AsRef` provides a different blanket implementation, basically `&T: AsRef<U>` whenever `T: AsRef<U>`, which is important for APIs like `fs::open` that can use a simpler and more flexible signature as a result. You can't have both blanket implementations due to coherence, so each trait is making the choice that's appropriate for its use case.

Answer (score 2):

I think that is one of the differences of `AsRef` and `Borrow`.

That is, `Borrow<T>` is implemented directly for `&T`, while `AsRef<T>` is not implemented for `&T`.

Funny thing is that `AsRef<U>` is implemented for `&T` if T implements `AsRef<U>`. That is, if you can use `AsRef` with a type, you can use it with a reference to the same time.

And another funny thing is that `Borrow<T>` is implemented for `&T` but also for `T`!